# Specify language for mapbox tiles in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I want to show the map in my app in English (no localized names in the language most people can't read)

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}',
```

I'm using mapbox tiles and it's working for me, but all the signs are shown in local languages. Since my app is in English, I don't want to show Chinese signs to my visitors.

I found the docs about how to change the language in mapbox.js, but I don't want to use their library. Is there a way to build tiles url so it would've been aware about the language preferences?

update: mapbox is not really an important requirement. I'm looking for the tile with labels in English. Can't find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Mapbox Classic you could change the map `{id}` to use `mapbox.run-bike-hike` which uses English globally. See https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps

Otherwise you would need to modify the default streets style as described at https://www.mapbox.com/help/change-language/#change-label-language-in-mapbox-studio-classic.

If you're Mapbox GL (rather than classic) the instructions are at https://www.mapbox.com/help/change-language/. You can still include raster tiles from your Mapbox GL style in your Leaflet application with https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles

Comment: I'm using classic option and `mapbox.run-bike-hike` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I know its almost 3 years later but I'm having this same problem, and I don't understand this answer.  The link says to use `map.setLayoutProperty('country-label', 'text-field', [
'get',
'name_' + language
]);`, but this is within the mapbox API, not the leaflet API.   The leaflet API doesn't have a `setLayoutProperty` method.  How can we get the desired language using an L.tilelayer('mapboxURL') layer in leaflet?

Comment: If you're not using Mapbox GL JS you can't dynamically set the language on the client, so you'll need to create a new style in Mapbox Studio with your text field using the field for your language

Comment: There are many layers which provide both english and native names. Try here http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1.** sign up https://studio.mapbox.com/, then sign in.

**Step 2.** desgin your own map style, change the Places componets language.

**Step 3.** save the style, and get the style URL `mapbox://styles/yourusername/randomstring`, in fact, **yourusername/randomstring** is the ID(id).

**Step 4.** use the id \ accessToken in  `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token={accessToken}`

refer to: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#vector-tiles
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the `z` is the `Zoom` value.

Comment: step3 ... and make public